# Python, how to randomly add/append elements from one list to another?

Tags: python, arrays, list, random, append

```
import random
global colours 
global current
colours = ["Red","Yellow","Blue","Green","Orange","White"]
current = []

def randompicker():
    for i in range(4):
        current = random.choice(colours)
randompicker()
print(colours)
print(current)
```

Hey, so the above program is supposed to randomly add 4 of the elements from the list called colours into the other list named current. I have looked through the forums, but I cannot find help specific to this case.

In short, Is there a quick and efficient way to add 4 random elements from one list straight into another?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your original code, do

```
current.append(random.choice(colours))
```

instead of

```
current = random.choice(colours)
```

You should also make `current` a local variable and return it rather than a global variable. In the same light, you should pass the array of choices as a parameter rather than working on a global variable directory. Both of these changes will give your function greater flexibility.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, is there a way that I could do this without the duplicates?

Comment: @JayHunkys sure. In words, you need to check the `current` list to see if it already contains the next choice before appending it. See how I start by describing the solution in English? I leave it up to you too refine this a little more so that you can translate it into code.

Comment: @JayHunkys alternatively, you can use a `set` which will do the check for you

Comment: Thank you, I got it all working now just how I wanted. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 6):

You're describing the basic usage of [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

```
>>> colours = ["Red","Yellow","Blue","Green","Orange","White"]
>>> random.sample(colours, 4)
['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Orange']
```

If you want to allow duplicates, use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead (new in Python 3.6).

```
>>> random.choices(colours, k=4)
['Green', 'White', 'White', 'Red']
```